# CSS/JQuery Loading Animation not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I have been trying to add a jquery Loading Indicator to my website:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Loading-Indicator-with-jQuery-CSS3/

The below call works as expected on all browsers except MacOS Safari (does work in iOS)

In MacOS Safari it simply does not show, I can trigger the animation by preventing the submit, but cannot load the animation and submit as desired.

The submit runs a php script which works as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#login-form').submit(function() {
            $('body').loadingIndicator();
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<form class="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="user_forgot.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="user_email">
        <input type="submit" name="reset_password" id="reset_password" VALUE = "Reset Password">
</form>
```

I have tried so many different ideas suggested, including onClick, ePrevent, programmatically calling submit via a Button, calling the loader via a variable and many others without success.

I am at a loss on how to get this to function in MacOS Safari.

Any suggestions or functional alternatives would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution (after 2 days!) I am not sure if this solution is correct, but it works!! For some reason the submit() within the setTimeout did't submit the script but calling click() does?

**Update:** This causes a loop in Chrome and IE as it appears that the different browsers handle the running of scripts after the submit event differently. I've got around this by adding .one() I'm sure this is not the best way and would be open to any suggestion on how to improve this.

```
<script>
                var submit = false;
                $("#login-form").one("submit" , function(e) {
                    $('body').loadingIndicator();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        submit = true;
                        $('#reset_password').click();
                    }, 1000);
                    if(!submit)
                        e.preventDefault();
                 });
</script>
```